# how to put two records same page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a page with exactly same pre-format data  in the left side than in the right and i need that my result query data  that gives me example 10 records i need to show in the left side first record, in the right side second record on first page and then do the same with all records Now i make a first report wich calls another one, first report gives me data but i can only show one record per page in second report, i need 2 records per page, one in left side and another in another side of the page...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each of your records will take up more than half a page, this should be as simple as changing the report to have 2 columns.

In iReport, select the report itself (top element) in the report inspector, then change the Columns property to 2. Alternatively, in the JRXML, add/change the attribute `columnCount` on the `jasperReport` element to 2.

If your records occupy less than half the page height each, you will end up with multiple records per column. To get around this, create a group with the expression `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` and check the "Start on a new column" property (set the `isStartNewColumn` attribute in JRXML). This will create a new column for each record.